# MyBatis Spring Boot pagination query is very slow in Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a SELECT statement that does regular pagination in Oracle 11g database. Query itself when issued raw (in SQL Developer, for example) is fast. However, when used with MyBatis, it gets so slow. I understand that MyBatis puts the result set into objects, but 5+ seconds is a quite long time.

So, I tried to use MyBatis related solutions like PageHelper and RowBounds. Using RowBounds didn't make a difference with current setting, both took 5+ seconds, while PageHelper took 12 seconds. I also tried to set "fetchSize", that did not help either.

I wonder if there's a solution to this problem. Maybe there is a way of executing the SQL directly against database, and handing the result set to MyBatis, if that even makes sense. If there's a way to improve the SQL, please let me know that as well.

Here's the query with MyBatis templating. Original query has a bit more fields.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT tmp.*, rownum rn
      FROM (SELECT HH.history_id,
                   N.data_title_1,
                   N.data_body_1,
                   HH.date_added,
                   HH.is_read
            FROM history HH
                     INNER JOIN submissions S ON S.history_id = HH.history_id
                     INNER JOIN data_savepoint N
                                ON S.data_savepoint_id = N.data_savepoint_id
            WHERE HH.name = #{name}
              AND HH.is_deleted = 0
              AND HH.status = #{status}
              AND N.is_deleted = 0
            ORDER BY date_added DESC
           ) tmp
      WHERE rownum <= ${limit}
     )
WHERE rn > #{offset}
```

Comment: How large is a typical `data_body_1`?  Can you see if it performs better when that column is omitted?

Comment: @MikeOrganek it is an `NVARCHAR2(500)` field.Removing that had no effect.

Comment: If the query itself is fast, it may be the mapping part that is consuming the time. Please add the following info : 1) the result map definition, 2) a few sample result rows 3) the approximate number of rows returned from the query 4) MyBatis version. If you could provide a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) that replicates the performance issue, I'd look into it.

Comment: Interestingly, when I tried to create a demo project, I tested that setting, and it was fast. The exact same query, the exact same object to map. So, can this slowness happen because of a lot of cache that MyBatis holds?

Comment: Um...it's hard to say. It could also be something outside MyBatis e.g. logging, connection pool, container. Now that you have both slow and fast projects, it should not be too hard for you to find the key difference. :)